# Arquillian test not failing

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, jboss-arquillian

When dependency injection in Arquillian test class fails, maven still claims that all tests are run and are passed. This is major issue if we have hundreds of tests and some tests show as Green in Jenkins, but in reality they are not driven at all.

Is there a way to make the above test fail in Jenkins/Maven? One can use any Interface long as there is no implementation added to deployment.

```
@ExtendWith(ArquillianExtension.class)
class FailingArquillianTestIssueIT {

@Inject
DummyInterface dummyInterface;

@Deployment(testable = true)
public static JavaArchive create() throws Exception {

    JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE,
            "beans.xml");

    return archive;

}

@Test
void test1() {

    assertTrue(false);

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Enable standard streams: `testLogging.showStandardStreams = true` (In gradle). And then check info messages in the output for something like "Not generating any bean definitions from <package> because ...", these messages might give you some clue.